# Upserting array into document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a json array with objects and I'm doing the following loop in order to upsert (insert or update) the data into MongoDB using mongoose:

```
var currentMiniApp;
 function retResult(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
 }

 for (var i = 0 ; i < miniappData.miniapps.length; i++) {
    currentMiniApp = new MiniApp(miniappData.miniapps[i]);
    MiniApp.findOneAndUpdate(
        {id: currentMiniApp.id},
        currentMiniApp,
        {upsert: true},
        retResult);
 }
```

How can I do it in one command without using a loop?
I want that the document will contain the items in the data array
My data looks like:

```
{
  "miniapps" : 
  [ 
  {
    "id":"app1",
    "icon" : "256fko6.png"
  }, 
  {
    "id":"app2",
    "icon" : "icon60x60.png"
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378895/update-query-is-not-working-in-express-js-with-mongodb

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator with the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) modifier in your upsert **[update](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmongoosejs.com%2Fdocs%2Fapi.html%23model_Model-update&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHElyXdt9HoWrqJR2At-3vnLUPbwQ)**. This update operation adds multiple values to an array unless the values are already present, in which case [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) does nothing to that array:

```
var miniAppids = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < miniappData.miniapps.length; i++) {
    currentMiniApp = new MiniApp(miniappData.miniapps[i]);
    miniAppids.push(currentMiniApp.id);
};

MiniApp.update(
    { "id": { "$in": miniAppids } }, 
    { "$addToSet": { "miniapps": { "$each": miniappData.miniapps } } }, 
    { "upsert": true }, 
    retResult
)
```

Comment: Thanks! but this ain't working for me, It just create new entry named 'miniapps' but it empty, also I don't want to add an entry that will contain array. I want that the array will be added as is, meaning I would have all items right under my document

Comment: @DorCohen Gotcha, under such circumstances where I have limited infor of how your document structure and the expected result looks like, I guess I could use some sample test documents to come up with a correct answer, can you update your question to include this please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378895/update-query-is-not-working-in-express-js-with-mongodb  @chridam  help me out